# Using buttons to load csv into chart

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

Anyone know how to load csv via buttons?

Like year 2017 2016 2015 so I load that csv into the chart...
I had it before but with highchart i can't do it.

Here is my full code i use.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/data/woonkamer/woonkamer2018.csv',
  success: function(csv) {
    $("#b").click(function() {
      $.get('/data/woonkamer/woonkamer2019.csv', function(data) {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
          data: {
            csv: csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Daily Temperature And humidity'
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: 'Malosa'
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
              second: '%H:%M:%S',
              minute: '%H:%M',
              hour: '%H:%M',
              day: '%e. %B',
              week: '%e. %b',
              month: '%b \'%y',
              year: '%Y'
            },
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000
          },

          yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
              text: 'Temp + Humid',
            },
            labels: {
              align: 'temp',
              x: 3,
              y: 16,
              format: '',
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
          }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
              text: "humid "
            },

            labels: {
              align: 'right',
              x: -3,
              y: 16,
              format: '{value:.,0f}'
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
          }],

          legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          tooltip: {

          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              cursor: 'pointer',
              point: {
                events: {
                  click: function(e) {
                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                      pageOrigin: {
                        x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                        y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                      },
                      headingText: this.series.name,
                      maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A-%e%b-%Y at %H:%M', this.x) + '<br/> ' +
                        '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + this.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix + '',
                      width: 200
                    });
                  }
                }
              },
              marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
              }
            }
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'Temperature',
              data: [],
              tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'c'
              }
            },
            {
              name: 'Humidity',
              data: [],
              tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Let's hope someone can help me with this.
I searched all over the forums, and i found some but can't get it to work
I did change the code now , but now when i open my chart i need to click the button first when i want to open the new csv... thats not what i want.
where do i need to place it ?

Regards

Comment: Doing another ajax call with onClick button is not a solution ? For example by using : https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Do you have any error in browser's javascript console? (F12)

Comment: @Ko2r hi, i did try that by adding this in the beginning: `$("#b").click(function () {
  
    $.get('/data/woonkamer/woonkamer2018.csv', function (data) {

  
 }   
    
);

});`  its my first time using charts, i see the button and the chart correct but when i click nothing happens can you help me ?

Comment: @nicolallias i get 404 ok

Comment: code 404 is an HTML error meaning that the content is not where you think (or does not exist). If you try to open the csv in your browser, where is it located?

Comment: @nicolallias i did change the path to another csv.. but no errors this time  and nothing happens

Comment: @nicolallias i did change the code now, check above. but when i open the chart it let me first click the button then it display the chart attached to that button,,, but thats not what i want, where do i need to put that line so i can get it correctly ?

Comment: Try to rephrase and make good use of punctuation, I have trouble to read you. Can you make a simple example on https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/llexl/ (edit it with your code, save the new version, show us the link). What do you want?

Comment: In the description you defined what you don't want but you didn't explain what you want. Please correct that.